# Handling promises when dealing with event listeners

Tags: actionscript-3, promise, deferred

Currently I'm using promises in an `AS3` project but this is also relative to `JS` projects.

Say I have this code, in `AS3`:

```
public function getFeed():Promise
{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(END_POINT);
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var dfd:Deferred = new Deferred();

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleGetFeedReady, false, 0, true);

    loader.load(request);

    return dfd.promise;
}

private function handleGetFeedReady(e:Event):void
{
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleGetFeedReady);

    vo.entries = JSON.decode(e.target.data);

    // resolve the dfd here
}
```

What I'd like to is somehow pass the `dfd` (deferred) object to my event handler. Now I know that I *could* use an anonymous function like so:

```
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void
{
    handleGetFeedReady(dfd, e);   
}, false, 0, true);
```

But I'd like to steer clear of using anonymous functions that are created each time I call the parent method (maybe I'm being too anal).

Another choice could be to create a class reference to the `dfd` object but this'll create problems when I want to call the method simultaneously.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Deferreds should NOT be passed on outside of the service class. That's exactly one of the problems Promises try to solve.

Comment: Why shouldn't they be passed outside the class?

Comment: Encapsulation. If you pass the deferred around, some other actor can resolve or reject the async operation even if they have nothing to do with it. Only the composing agent should have access to the deferred and return the Promise. Also, the clients should not care how many async steps the service is taking. If the final promise is returned, they are left unaware. With Deferreds they aren't (two async processes can run in parallel, so in that case it has no use to return only one of the Deferreds, you'd need to return both. And you're back to square one)

Comment: Sorry my code doesn't explain it well but the deferred object doesn't get passed back to my actor, only the promise; the deferred object is used in the model call's event handlers to (rightly) resolve or reject.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood your question!

Answer (score 0):

So this is a potential answer, not sure if it's the *correct* method but it's suiting the problem and the project for now: I extended `URLLoader` and added a class variable relative to the loader that holds the `dfd` object, like so:

```
package com.domain
{
    import com.codecatalyst.promise.Deferred;

    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class URLDeferredLoader extends URLLoader
    {
        private var _dfd:Deferred;

        public function URLDeferredLoader(dfd:Deferred, request:URLRequest=null)
        {
            super(request);

            this._dfd = dfd;
        }

        public function get dfd():Deferred
        {
            return _dfd;
        }
    }
}
```

It does the job quite nicely!